# bq command line tool - How to insert into Big query tables that has nested fields?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have three BigQuery tables as shown below

**Employee**

```
Employee_id | Department_id | Location_id | Name | Age
```

**Department**

```
Department_id | Department_Name | Department_Code
```

**Location**

```
Location_id | Country | State | City
```

Below Query is used to join all three tables,

```
SELECT
  e.Employee_id,
  e.Name,
  e.Age,
  e.Department_id,
  d.Department_Name,
  d.Department_Code,
  l.Location_id,
  l.Country , 
  l.State,
  l.City
FROM Employee e
JOIN Department d
  ON e.Department_id = d. Department_id
JOIN Location l
  ON e.Location_id = l.Location_id
```

How to insert this result set into BigQuery table which has below schema with nested fields using bq command line utility(bq query command)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to insert this result set into BigQuery table which has below schema with nested fields?

Below is for [BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)

```
SELECT
    e.Employee_id,
    e.Name,
    e.Age,
    STRUCT<Department_id STRING, Department_Name STRING, Department_Code STRING>(
                  e.Department_id, d.Department_Name, d.Department_Code) AS Department,
    STRUCT<Location_id STRING, Country STRING, State STRING, City STRING>(
                                l.Location_id, l.Country, l.State, l.City) AS Location
FROM Employee e
JOIN Department d
    ON e.Department_id = d. Department_id
JOIN Location l
    ON e.Location_id = l.Location_id
```

> ... using bq command line utility(bq query command)?

`` bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --append_table --destination_table 'dataset.table' '**`above query`**' ``

see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#bigquery-enable-sql-cli) and [bq-command-line-tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool) for more details

Comment: Thanks. Works as expected. But how to represent multi-level(nested record within nested field) nested fields in query?

Comment: Resolved myself. Should be represented as below,
`SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
  Struct<Parent_id String, Child Struct< id INT64, name String> >
  ("Parent_id", (1,"name"))
  FROM
  Your_Table
`

Comment: Struct is not supported in Legacy SQL. How to achieve the same in Legacy SQL?