# BigQuery Legacy SQL - How to insert into tables that has nested fields?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to insert records into tables that has Nested and Repeated fields. I know that STRUCT and ARRAY keyword can be used respectively in Standard SQL.

What is equivalent of STRUCT and ARRAY keyword in Legacy SQL to insert records into Nested and Repeated fields?

Comment: I'll ask the obvious question...Why use legacy SQL for this purpose? It has fairly severe limitations related to constructing query results nested and repeated fields.

Comment: @vetri - as Elliot states, you really should be moving toward using standard SQL in BigQuery in your solutions, and getting off legacy SQL.

Comment: Sure. I understand the advantages of Standard SQL. So migrating to Standard SQL. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am reusing example you provided in [bq command line tool - How to insert into Big query tables that has nested fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41196040/5221944)

Try below, it is for Legacy SQL and using in-line version of [Javascript UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) for Legacy SQL
Note: by default BigQuery Legacy SQL flattens any result, so make sure you set destination table and set `Allow Large Results` to true (or check it in Web UI) and `Flatten Results` to false (or uncheck it in Web UI)

```
SELECT Employee_id, Name, Age, Department.*, Location.* FROM JS((
  SELECT Employee_id, Name, Age, Department_id, Department_Name, Department_Code, e.Location_id AS Location_id, Country,  State,  City 
  FROM (SELECT e.Employee_id AS Employee_id, e.Name AS Name, e.Age AS Age,
      e.Department_id AS Department_id, d.Department_Name AS Department_Name, d.Department_Code AS Department_Code, e.Location_id AS Location_id
    FROM Employee e JOIN Department d ON e.Department_id = d.Department_id ) AS e
  JOIN Location l ON e.Location_id = l.Location_id
),
// input columns
Employee_id,  Name, Age,  Department_id, Department_Name, Department_Code,  Location_id,  Country,  State,  City,  
// output schema
"[
  {'name': 'Employee_id', 'type': 'INTEGER', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
  {'name': 'Name', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
  {'name': 'Age', 'type': 'INTEGER', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
  {'name': 'Department', 'type': 'RECORD', 'mode': 'NULLABLE', 'fields': [
      {'name': 'Department_id', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
      {'name': 'Department_Name', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
      {'name': 'Department_Code', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}
    ]},
  {'name': 'Location', 'type': 'RECORD', 'mode': 'NULLABLE', 'fields': [
      {'name': 'Location_id', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
      {'name': 'Country', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
      {'name': 'State', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
      {'name': 'City', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}
    ]}
]",
// function
"function(r, emit){
  emit({
    Employee_id: r.Employee_id, Name: r.Name, Age: r.Age,
    Department: {Department_id:r.Department_id, Department_Name:r.Department_Name, Department_Code:r.Department_Code}, 
    Location: {Location_id:r.Location_id, Country:r.Country, State:r.State, City:r.City}
  });
}"
)
```

Please note: i am using in-line version of UDF here for the purpose of easy showing and testing. In-line version is not recommended and not officially supported. But you can easily convert it to supported version - see more for [User-Defined Functions in Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions)

P.S. even though above works and helped a lot before the Standard SQL was an option - now what is the big reason for you to use Legacy SQL where Standard SQL is more elegant and gives you much more flexibility especially when it is about dealing with nested and repeated fields

Comment: Thanks. I'm using tableau 9.3 to connect with BigQuery and it doesn't seem to support Standard SQL. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is it about Tableau version 9.3 that makes you unwilling to upgrade to anything past it? You can read [Tableau's upgrade guide](http://www.tableau.com/support/server-upgrade), for instance. That version of Tableau was released more than six months ago now.

Comment: Upgraded tableau to version 10.1 and will go with BigQuery Standard SQL which has additional features. Thanks all.